# Apache Camel move file after processing

Tags: apache-camel

Is there a way to move a file named 'yyyy-x.zip' after processing to a folder 'yyyy/yyyy-x.zip' by the file component? I thought of following:

```
from("file://directory?preMove=working&move=${${file:onlyname}.substring(0,3)}/${file:onlyname}&moveFailed=error")
.doStuff(...);
```

But i get always the following exception.

```
    org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleIllegalSyntaxException: Unknown function: ${file:onlyname}.toString().subString(0,3) at location 0 ${${file:onlyname}.toString().subString(0,3)}/${file:onlyname}
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionStart$1.evaluate(SimpleFunctionStart.java:107)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.ExpressionBuilder$75.evaluate(ExpressionBuilder.java:1795)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ExpressionAdapter.evaluate(ExpressionAdapter.java:36)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileExpressionRenamer.renameFile(GenericFileExpressionRenamer.java:37)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.commit(GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.processStrategyCommit(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:127)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.onCompletion(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.onComplete(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.util.UnitOfWorkHelper.doneSynchronizations(UnitOfWorkHelper.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork.done(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:230)
    at org.apache.camel.util.UnitOfWorkHelper.doneUow(UnitOfWorkHelper.java:65)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.after(CamelInternalProcessor.java:674)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.after(CamelInternalProcessor.java:629)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$InternalCallback.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:246)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:460)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:227)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleParserException: Unknown function: ${file:onlyname}.toString().subString(0,3)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionExpression.createSimpleExpression(SimpleFunctionExpression.java:230)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionExpression.createExpression(SimpleFunctionExpression.java:45)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionStart$1.evaluate(SimpleFunctionStart.java:104)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the tip from Claus Ibsen I managed to get the following solution:

```
from("file://directory?preMove=working&move=${bean:myBean.myMethod(${file:onlyname})}&moveFailed=error")
.doStuff(...);
```

With the following Bean:

```
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("myBean")
public class MyBeanImpl() implements MyBean{

        @Override
        public String myMethod(String fileName){
            return ...create the filename...; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly in the uri use the complex functions with substring et all.

You can use a bean to compute the name, and use `move=${bean:myBean.myMethod}` and then register a bean with id `myBean` in the registry which then computes the name.